# 3 аргумент функции strtok

Tags: c, строки

Какой 3 аргумент должен быть у функции strtok_s()?

```
char *pch = strtok_s(str," ");
```

Такой вариант выдаёт ошибку

Comment: А что об этом говорится в [документации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok)?

Answer (score 1):

Вот сигнатура функции:

```
char *strtok_s(char *restrict str, rsize_t *restrict strmax,
    const char *restrict delim, char **restrict ptr);
```

Первый и третий параметры такие же, как в `strtok`; второй - по этому адресу записывается, сколько еще символов осталось просмотреть, а в последнем - контекст для последующих вызовов.

Вот [описание с примером применения](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

Comment: А можете пример кода дать?

Comment: Вы по ссылке ходили? Я же написал - с примером применения, там код есть...